# WP development locally - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

I'm using Linux Mint 13 (Ubuntu 12.04 based) and trying to install a local development environment of a WordPress production project which right now is in an amazon EC2 instance.

First, I cloned WP project from its bitbucket repository.

After, I made a db environment backup with:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --lock-tables=false --all-databases > dump-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql
```

Then I imported it to my computer with:

```
 scp my-server:~/db_backups/db_backup.sql ~/mylocalfolderforbackups
```

I installed the db environment backup in my local mysql with:

```
 mysql -u root -p < db_backup.sql
```

My wp-config.php is filled as following (thought I don't know if my WP copy uses wp-config.php.prod instead):

```
define('DB_NAME', 'prod_db'); //because I've restored the production db backup
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'); //where I put the right password for root user
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost');
```

I've restarted apache and mysql but when I try to access to http://localhost/my-project/ it returns "Error establishing a database connection". I don't find the issue... Do you have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: I assume other websites connect to other databases using those credentials correctly and can you access /wp-admin/ ? Try using the IP 127.0.0.1 instead of `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Error establishing a database connection` doesn't get any simpler than that. Your password, database name, user name, or host is wrong. WordPress won't use `wp-config.php.prod`, only `wp-config.php`. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Error_Establishing_Database_Connection

Try

`mysql> show databases;`

to list all databases to check the database name.

Try

`mysql> mysqlserverinfo --server=root:pass@localhost -d --format=vertical`

to get port info, etc. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqlserverinfo.html

Or, try using Adminer http://www.adminer.org/ on your PC/Mac to find the database name, etc.

Comment: I have created a new wp-config.php based on wp-config-sample.php filling everything again and now it works... though it doesn't charge any css and js files.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the name of the mysql database used by wordpress and set the DB_NAME in your wp-config.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue... I just forgot to paste it into the post. I've edited it to include the DB_NAME.